# I can't get my html to link to css files on the server

Tags: html, css, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I just started setting up my first live personal site, which I am hosting through iPage. Despite the fact that everything worked great on my local environment, I cannot get the html to link to the css files on the server. I have inlcuded a picture that shows the directory structure and relevant code. The file I am working with is calculator.html.

[image]

{edit} Obviously the uploaded picture is too small to see, so here is a link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTdp.png

I also tried uploading the stylesheet to the same directory as calculator.html and changing the href of the link element to "buttonstyle1.css" but this did not work either.

Additionally, I can't figure out where in their directory structure I am supposed to put my index.html such that www.abc.com(obviously not the real domain) would call the index file. With the index file in it's current position I have to type www.abc.com/index.html.

Ignore the Home.html, that is a file that they provided and I haven't deleted yet. But even for that I have to type www.abc.com/Home.html to reach it. Typing www.abc.com results in nothing, just a default ISP search result page.

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: The issue of having to go to abc.com/index.html would suggest that this is the reason for the css issues as well. Is there any way for you to see the directory structure on your server?

Comment: There is yes. It seems to look the same as what I see in Notepad++ though

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lHZWj5t.png

Comment: @Slaks I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the tools provided by the web host?

Comment: Try putting a dot like ./css/xy.css maybe

Comment: Well after some more googling I found that apparently iPage does some sort of caching that prevents any change you make, no matter how minor, from taking immediate effect.

http://andrewapeterson.com/2011/02/ipage-css-changes-not-taking-effect-due-to-cache-youre-not-crazy-and-its-not-your-fualt/

So now that it's been 15 minutes or so I was able to refresh and viola! It's fine. Pretty god damn annoying though. Supposedly it's something they can turn off and I'm certainly going to try to get them to do so.

Comment: Side note, it's probably pointless to have an id on your link tag.

Comment: The id is so I can access it with javascript, to change the href and thus the linked stylesheet

Comment: No; the browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me on Ipage is putting a `/` before the link. That will tell the server that it needs to start for the root path.